# How to check if query is equal to more then one string?

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
if($_GET['uinput'] == "text1" xor "text2" xor "text3") {
   echo "";
} else {
   echo "ERROR: Query string ['uinput'] contains not allowed string." . "</br>";
   die();
}
```

Example:

1.

- Input: `?uinput=text1`
- Output: nothing

2. 

- Input: `?uinput=text2`
- Output: `ERROR: Query string ['uinput'] contains not allowed string.`

The code is only checking if `uinput` is equal to `text1`. It is not checking if `uinput` could be equal to `text2` or `text3`.

How can I fix, that the code is checking if `uinput` is equal for everything after `==`?

Answer (score 2):

You can't only specify the left-side of the expression once, you have to put the full expression you want to test in each clause.

---

Your idea doesn't work because your original expression evaluates separately, whether `$_GET['uinput'] == "text1"` returns true or false, whether `"test2"` returns true or false, and whether `"test3"` returns true or false. Then it puts them together to evaluate the whole expression.

Since those non-empty strings are truth-y (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php), for the input `?uinput=text2`, your expression is boiled down to

```
(false xor true xor true)
```

And since you're using xor, meaning that both sides of a xor cannot be true, the final result is `false`.

---

To work, it would need to be

```
if( $_GET['uinput'] == "text1" xor $_GET['uinput'] == "text2" xor $_GET['uinput'] == "text3") {
```

---

Alternatively, you can make it neater and less repetitive by using an array:

```
$vals = array ("text1", "text2", "text3");

if (in_array($_GET['uinput'], $vals)) {
```

Documentation:

1. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php
2. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

```
if($_GET['uinput'] == "text1" || $_GET['uinput'] == "text2" || $_GET['uinput'] == "text3")
```